# gnome-control-center suddenly has limited settings

Tags: unity, gnome

I remember normally I can make most of the settings just by typing the name in Unity search, like when I type "Displays" I can configure my monitors. But all of sudden the "Displays" is no longer available. Specifically, now I type "settings" nothing shows up anymore. I launch gnome-control-center from terminal but only very limited number settings show up under "all settings". I type "sudo gnome-control-center" then I can see all settings. But why is that? I surely don't want to type password every time when I just wan to switch monitor.

Comment: I just encountered this as well. It was very frustrating when I tried to change things in my system and the option to do so suddenly disappeared. I can't even ACCESS system settings without using the command line anymore...